# Is there any way in python to terminate the input sequence by input -1?

Tags: python

**E.g.:**

> Enter the sequence S : 30 15 36 12 34 96 11 4 5 7 -1

After input -1 the input sequence must be auto terminated.

Comment: input should be in a single line or can span to multiple lines?

Comment: you information is to limited.

Comment: Input should be in a single line.I usually stop getting input  by pressing the  "Enter" button. But  I want to stop it by entering -1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
arr=[]
x=int(raw_input())
while x!=-1:
    arr.append(x)
    x=int(raw_input())
arr.append(x)
print arr #your input sequence in form of list
```

Note : This code will take a single integer in a single line i.e. the input will span to multiple lines till you input -1.

Comment: According to this code, I have to input a number and press "Enter" button then next number. But I want to get next input in same line. Finally when it input  -1, program must stop getting any more inputs. (Then it prints entered numbers.)

Comment: That isn't possible according to my knowledge. You could see what @posh_pumpkin did but for that you need the whole input in a list and then trim it till you find -1 but i suppose that doesn't solve the problem in hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. I have two guess so I'll answer those instead.

First guess: User inputs multiple times until -1. (Without any input validation)

```
user_input = 0
while user_input != -1:
    user_input = input("Enter :")
```

Second guess: You have a long list of integers that has a -1 somewhere, and you want to trim the list there (delimited by -1).

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 6]
trimmed = []
for item in lst:
    if item == -1:
        break
    else: trimmed.append(item)
print(trimmed)
```